# Ruby CanCanCan reverse user lookup, faster way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I have extended the user model to allow me to do `.can?` checks on the user.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def ability
    @ability = Ability.new self
  end
  delegate :can?, :cannot?, :to => :ability
end
```

This allows me to do things like `@some_user.can? :edit, Book` and get a result.  (The cancan view helper, but in the model.). This works great.

I'd like to be able to do a reverse of that though and get all users that can do an action.

Example:  Give me all users that can :edit, Books.  `User.can? :edit, Book` which returns an active record collection.

To get this to work I did this;

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.can? sym, obj, *args
    uids = []
    User.all.each do |user|
      uids << user.id if user.can? sym, obj, args
    end
    User.where id: uids
  end
end
```

While this works, it feels really icky as it's iterating through each user and I'm concerned about scale.. is there a faster way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

i suggest combine cancan with [rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify), with `rolify` you could pre-setup roles for users then your problem will turn into a query users who have the `edit Book role`

```rb
member_user.add_role :read, Book
admin_user.add_role :edit, Book

# query
User.with_role(:edit, Book) # [admin_user]
User.without_role(:edit, Book) # [member_user]
```